# keep id in name field from mysql database

Tags: java, swing

I have a login UI. when login is perform user id and login id insert into logging table.
UI have username field, password field and branch field.when name , password ,branch is fill and press login button user id and logdate insert into logging table. how i can solve this.

insert table in logging table...........

```
public User  insertuserloginDate(Connection con,int userid,Timestamp logtime){

    String sql="INSERT into logging values(?,?,?)";
    String sql1="Select * from user";

    try {

           Statement stm=con.createStatement();
    //               ResultSet rs=stm.executeQuery(sql1);
    //               while (rs.next()){
                       User u=new User(rs.getInt(1));
   //                  return u;
                     }

        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1, userid);
        ps.setTimestamp(2, logtime);
        ps.setInt(3, getRecord());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
        con.close();

    }  catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error while login record " + ex);

}
   return null;
```

and in button action............

```
private void buttonloginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   

    char[] temp_pwd = userpassword.getPassword();
    String pwd = null;
    pwd = String.copyValueOf(temp_pwd);
    System.out.println("password " + pwd);

    //try {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (user.loginApplication(connect.getCon(), username.getText(),
            pwd, userbranch.getSelectedItem().toString())) {

        System.out.println("success ");
        MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
        mainForm.setVisible(true);

        user.insertuserloginDate(connect.getCon(), user.getUid(), user.getLogdate());
        System.out.println("record user log time " +user.getUid());
       // user.getuser(connect.getCon());

    }else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Failed!", "Failed!",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you already tried ?

Comment: String sql="INSERT into logging values(?,?,?)";
    String sql1="Select * from user";

    try {




         Statement stm=con.createStatement();

// ResultSet rs=stm.executeQuery(sql1); // while (rs.next())

{ User u=new User(rs.getInt(1)); // return u; }

        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1, userid);
        ps.setTimestamp(2, logtime);
        ps.setInt(3, getRecord());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
        con.close();

Answer (score 1):

You can do with 2 steps like below:

step1:check the username and password combination is correct,and get user_id from database

```
sql ="select id from user_table where username='%s'" %(username)
user_id = db.exexute(sql).fetchone()
```

step2:save the datetime and user_id to your logging table

```
now = datetime.now()
sql = "insert into log_table values (%d,'%s')".%(user_id,now)
db.execute(sql)
```

Comment: That is the python syntax,you need translate it to Java code. the 'db' is a database cursor in my code.